# Query between two dates from excel using c#, but the problem is I am getting the wrong dates as the result

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, sqlbulkcopy, excel-dates

Below is my code. I get my dates from two `DatePicker`s in a Windows Form. I am trying to get the rows in Excel that are in between those two dates and do a `SqlBulkCopy` to SQL Server. I am getting the wrong dates as a result.

I have tried using a `TextBox` instead of `DatePicker` but that doesn't work either.

```
using (SqlConnection strConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
{
    using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
    {
        var buttons = (new[] { groupBox1 }
            .SelectMany(g => g.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
            .Where(r => r.Checked)))
            .ToList();

        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();

        if (buttons[0].Text == "Date Range")
        {
            query.CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet0$]  where [ChangedDate] between @date1 and @date2;";
        }
        else
        {
            query.CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet0$]";
        }

        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query.CommandText, excelConnection))
        {
            if (buttons[0].Text == "Date Range")
            {
                string fromDate = this.fromDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                string toDate = this.toDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");                                   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", fromDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", toDate);
            }                               

            excelConnection.Open();
            using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {                
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
                    null))
                {
                    e.Result = 0;
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "tblCMHC";

                    while (dReader.Read())
                    {                        
                        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dates in Excel are, well, special.  They are floating point numbers with the integer part representing the day (as days since the start of the Excel epoch) and the fractional part, the time of day (for example, if the fractional part is 0.5, then it represents noon).  Have you checked if the SQL interface to Excel handles dates in a SQL-ish way or in an Excel-ish way?

Comment: If you want to see the floating point value of a date in Excel, change the format of the cell to a numeric format (from a date format).  For example, I'm in the Central North American time zone (Central Daylight Saving Time) and right now (15:03, on 19-Mar-2019) shows up as 43543.6309974537

Comment: Both `Date.ToString()` and `AddWithValue` are always risky in databases, try `cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", OleDbType.DateTime).Value = this.fromDate.Value`.

Comment: DateTime in c# has a method called `ToOADate()` which is used to convert c# dates to Excel understandable format. You can give it a try. Check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Tried both ToOADate() and cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", OleDbType.DateTime).Value = this.fromDate.Value. Yet, not working!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Problem was not with my code. In fact I was getting the right search results from excel but I needed to change the format of date column in excel to be able to insert records into SQL server database in the acceptable format.